# SwiftでreadLineで入力ができない

Tags: swift4

かなり初歩的な内容なのですが、Swiftで`readline()`を使ってEOFが入力されるまで入力を出力し続けるというコードを書いてます。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        while let input = readLine() {
            print(input)
        }

        print("end")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

上記のコードを実行すると入力をする前にendが出力されてしまい困惑しています。デバッガを使って一行一行みていくとwhile文の判別式からprint("end")に飛んでしまっていることが確認できました。

`readLine()`のドキュメンテーションを読むと、

> If EOF has　already been reached when `readLine()` is called, the result is `nil`.

と書いてあるのですが、これは`while let input = readLine()`の行へ行く前にすでにEOFが返されてしまっているということなのでしょうか…？

補足：　xcodeの実行環境はVersion 9.4.1 (9F2000)です。

Comment: コードを見るとiOS用のもののようですが、iOSアプリでは「標準入力」と言ったものが使える状態にないので、`readLine()`を使用することはできません。`readLine()`を使用する簡単なコードを試したいのであれば、Command Line Toolとして、macOS用のプロジェクトを作成してください。

Comment: iosでは標準入力がそもそもなかったのですね...。御回答ありがとうございました。